# Titanium iPhone Mapview not displaying Title or subtitle from pin annotation

Tags: javascript, ios, maps, titanium

I have an issue with mapview.
When i am using titanium sdk 3.0.2.GA then title and subtitle shown on pin,
But when i am using titanium sdk 3.1.0.GA then title and subtitle not shown on pin.

My code is below

```
function LocationUIWindow(title) {
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:title,
    backgroundColor:'#222222'
});

self.barColor = '#c61b17';

var h = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;

self.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT];

createMapView(self,33.74511,-84.38993);

return self;
};

function createMapView(win,lat,lng){
var atlantaParams = {
    latitude:lat,
    longitude:lng,
    title:"Atlanta, GA",
    subtitle:'Atlanta Braves Stadium\nfoo',
    animate:true,
    myid:3, // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE THAT IS PASSED INTO EVENT OBJECTS
    pincolor : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_PURPLE
};

var atlanta = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation(atlantaParams);
```

// CREATE MAP VIEW

```
var presetAnnotations = [atlanta];
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region:{latitude:lat, longitude:lng, latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:presetAnnotations
});

mapview.addAnnotation(atlanta);
mapview.selectAnnotation(atlanta);
win.add(mapview);
}

module.exports = LocationUIWindow;
```

How can I fix it in titanium sdk 3.1.0.GA?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work, you have to call the **selectAnnotation** function after the window is opened.

Thus, you just have to change this code :

```
mapview.addAnnotation(atlanta);
mapview.selectAnnotation(atlanta);
```

into this one :

```
mapview.addAnnotation(atlanta);
win.addEventListener('open', function(e){
    mapview.selectAnnotation(atlanta);
});
```

Then, you can remove the **mapview.addAnnotation(atlanta)** part. It is useless since you have already added your annotation with the **annotations** property of **Titanium.Map.createView**.

Thus, you final code will be :

```
win.addEventListener('open', function(e){
    mapview.selectAnnotation(atlanta);
});
```

This code works for me with **3.1.0.GA**.